# Using colors from a different swatch in MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using `MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit` in my WPF application. As described in the documentation [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Super-Quick-Start), I've set a primary and accent color for the entire app in my `App.xaml` main file.

However, there are some places in my app where I would like to use colors from a different swatch than the one defined in my App.xaml.

Is there an easy way to do this? Something like:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniButton}" Height="32" Width="32"
    Background="{StaticResource MaterialDesignColors.Amber.Primary"> <!-- something like this... -->
    ...
</Button>
```

or something similar. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done but it's a bit of a faff, you need to add the swatch to your resources

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.Accent.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>   
  </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And then you can create a brush using the colour you want from the swatch

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniButton}" Height="32" Width="32">
   <Grid.Background>
     <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Accent700}"/>
   </Grid.Background>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is pretty straightforward. However what I wonder is: is there a way to import multiple swatches this way? Because I presume that with that code you can only import one, since you're then referencing the "Accent700" brush without qualifying it with "Lime" anywhere... so I presume that you can only import one swatch, which will import all its brushes. Is there a way to assign keys to the imported swatches, so I can then do something like `<SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Lime.Accent700}"/>` or similar?